# Syncing Nx library source code between two repositories

Tags: github

I'm searching for a method to share certain libraries/components/storybook source code across repositories. This would allow the same library source code to be available and buildable in both repositories. Consequently, anyone would be able to view all available components and select the ones they need. This approach would enable my colleagues and I to reuse the central library code and incorporate it into the applications within this repository. Additionally, this strategy eliminates the need for updating the library in both repositories separately, as they would either be synchronized or sourced from a central location.

This raises a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to synchronize the library across different repositories?
2. Should I establish a central library that allows pushing code into these repositories?